Нужна помощь с параметром куки BX_USER_ID
При открытии сайта(он на Битриксе и D7 фреймворке) до согласия с сбором куков, там уже хранятся некоторые параметры, среди которых BX_USER_ID
Мне нужно чтобы его не было, удаление с помощью js, php не помогает, советы от нейронок тоже,
Кто смог отменить запись данного параметра, помогите.
